# Using the StackExchange API to search on keywords

Tags: stackexchange-api, offline-browsing

I'm thinking about writing an app that lets you download data from StackOverflow. There is one caveat: I want to download data that contains specified keywords. For example: if you search for "How do I implement an interface in Java?" you get the questions that the search functions returns, and these will be downloaded for offline viewing.

My question is: is this even possible with the StackExchange API? There exist a get method for /questions, and a get method for questions{id}. But I can't find a get method for a search function anywhere in the API docs.

Anybody knows more?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: /Search. Overlooked it!